# Socat device disappears

Tags: ubuntu, socat

On Ubuntu 18.04, I'm using socat to connect to a USB device physically attached to another machine (and exposed via ser2net):

`sudo socat PTY,link=/dev/zwavevera,group=root,mode=777 TCP:vera.home.lan:7676`

The socat command executes successfully and I can see the established connection in netstat. I can also see the new device in `/dev`, but only temporarily. After a little while, `/dev/zwavevera` disappears but the socat connection is still alive:

`netstat -a | grep 7676
tcp        0      0 192.168.10.199:41262    192.168.10.112:7676     ESTABLISHED`

The above works just fine on a Synology NAS, where a docker container needs the device. Now I want to migrate that container to a dedicated Ubuntu machine but I'm stuck with this problem.

What happens to the device? Can I find it and use it in some other way?

Comment: Try to use the `strace` command to investigate what happens inside `socat`. It shouldn't be very hard to understand. Or just paste the output to the question and I'll try to help you in troubleshooting.

Comment: Besides, you probably don't want `group=root,mode=777`.

Comment: Strangely enough, it stopped doing that after a reboot.